# Getting the value of selected checkboxes from CheckBoxList created in c#

Tags: c#, jquery, css

This should be straight forward for anyone who's done it previously, apologies if this has been answered before but I can't seem to find it if so.

I'm building a solution in c# vb.net and when adding CheckBoxList items I'm trying to apply the same class to each of them. this will enable me to manipulate another field based on what's checked by the end user.

I've tried the 2 following code snippets. From what I've read they both should work, but when I've checked it in dom explorer it hasn't added the class :/

snippet 1

```
        private void GetProjectManagers()
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["tablename"].ConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())

                {

                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT FullName,PrimaryID FROM TBL_ProjectManagers ORDER BY FullName ASC;";
                    cmd.Connection = connection;
                    connection.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (sdr.Read())
                        {
                            ListItem item = new ListItem();
                            item.Text = sdr["FullName"].ToString();
                            item.Value = sdr["PrimaryID"].ToString();
                            cbProjectManager.Items.Add(item);
                            cbProjectManager.Attributes.Add("class","ProjectManagerCheckbox");
                        }
                    }
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }

    }
```

snippet 2

```
        private void GetProjectManagers()
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["tablename"].ConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())

                {

                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT FullName,PrimaryID FROM TBL_ProjectManagers ORDER BY FullName ASC;";
                    cmd.Connection = connection;
                    connection.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (sdr.Read())
                        {
                            ListItem item = new ListItem();
                            item.Text = sdr["FullName"].ToString();
                            item.Value = sdr["PrimaryID"].ToString();
                            item.Attributes.Add("class", "ProjectManagerCheckbox");
                            cbProjectManager.Items.Add(item);
                        }
                    }
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }

    }
```

Thanks

elboffor

::edit::
thanks for pointing out in the comments that CssClass is what I needed to add a class, now my jQuery code does fire.
but for some reason it isn't picking up the value of the boxes checked.
what I'm doing is tring to concatenate the values of all checked boxes into one textbox field.

here is my jquery

```
            $(".ProjectManagerCheckbox").on("change", function () {
            var compiled = ($(".ProjectManagerCheckbox:checkbox:checked").map(function () {
                return this.value;
            }).get().join(", "));
            alert(compiled);
            $("#tbCompiledProjectManager").val(compiled);
```

Comment: Why there is a VB.NET tag? Your code is written in c#.

Comment: that's my noobism matey, I started writing in this the day before yesterday and started with a vb.net template in visual studio and chose c# as my language.

Comment: I can see the class just fine. Im unsure if u want to add the class to the control or its items, for the latter you must use cbProjectManager.Items[ItemIndex].Attributes.Add("class", "ProjectManagerCheckbox");

Comment: effectively I want every checkbox element it generates to have the class such as <input type='checkbox' class='ProjectManagerCheckbox' value='checkboxValue' /> so when it's ticked I can grab it's value in a jquery event and use it in a function on another part of the page.
When I check it in DOM explorer it doesn't have the class associated to it.

Comment: Can you share your `css` perhaps? Also you can set the class in the `CheckBoxList` instead of each item... Are you sure you want to set the class and ***not the style*** instead? For example (setting the class on the CheckBoxList): `<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkboxlist" runat="server" CssClass="ProjectManagerCheckbox" />`

Comment: well adding it as a CssClass did work to get my jquery event to fire but for some reason it isn't grabbing the value of the checked element. Back to the drawing board I think. Thanks for the replies though peeps, it's much appreciated

Comment: @elboffor Glad to hear! It would have helped if you supplied what was asked to help you further :) Good luck!

Comment: I've amended my question to fully explain :)
 Thanks for the support @Zaggler and everyone else

Comment: Could you please make this a new question. The original was addressed, but you have a different one now. This helps as well if any one else has this issue and needs help. Thanks and you are welcome!

Comment: `var compiled = $('#parentDivOfCheckBox').find('input:checked');` ... try that. That should give you an array of items that are checked...